# Creating folder using Sharpbox

Tags: vb.net, upload, cloud, dropbox, sharpbox

I am trying to create folder in my Dropbox using Sharpbox (the code is in vb.net).

I have a string variable named "str".
This is the code I use:

```
Dim dropBoxStorage = New CloudStorage()
Dim dropBoxConfig = CloudStorage.GetCloudConfigurationEasy(nSupportedCloudConfigurations.DropBox)
Dim str As String = "TheNameForMyFolder"
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(myfilepath)
Dim srcFile = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(myfilepath)
dropBoxStorage.CreateFolder("/" + str)
Dim publicFolder = dropBoxStorage.GetFolder("/" + str)
dropBoxStorage.UploadFile(srcFile, publicFolder)
```

A exception happens:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'AppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.Exceptions.SharpBoxException' occurred in AppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.dll
```

The exception happened at this line:

```
dropBoxStorage.CreateFolder("/" + str)
```

What have I done wrong, and what shall I do instead?

Comment: First add a try catch and check the exception message and maybe stacktrace. And a bit mor code would be fine ... is dropBoxStorage already opened?

Comment: Yes. I added my app to the dropbox App Console. I will add another lines of code soon.

Comment: I can't see dropBoxStorage.Open() anywhere, is it not there or are you not calling it?

Comment: I am not calling it. I flund a code for c#, but it don't work at vbnet after I converted it to vb.net. Do you know how to write that line in vb.net?

Comment: added an answer with the a link to example in the sharpbox forums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the connection with dropBoxStorage.Open().

Good example is available on [Codeplex](http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/discussions/270696) (VB.NET)

Comment: What do I need to write instead "Storageprovider"? Beacuse Visual studio don't recognize it.

Comment: I found solution: You just need to put the access token instead of the dropBoxCredentials. Thank you!